# Are Career salaries tax included or excluded?

Tags: support, jobs

Are careers.stackoverflow.com salaries tax included or excluded? 
Should we detract the taxes from it?

For example, it says that in Germany the salary for a senior software engineer is 57,000$. Is this the "take-home" profit or will I get just the half of it because of the taxes?

Comment: I've never heard of a job being advertised with the post-tax salary; only the gross (pre-tax salary). Is it common in Germany to advertise the post-tax salary?

Comment: IME salaries have also been pre-tax - they have to be because the tax rates and the administration of them are outside the scope of the company offering the salary. I've also seen it where other subtractions are still included in the grand figure, like mandatory superannuation contributions.

Comment: In many (most?) countries, taxes vary wildly from person to person, depending on marital status, dependent children, etc. so any salary advertised will be the gross salary. For Germany, you can use tools like [this](https://www.bmf-steuerrechner.de/) to calculate your approximate net salary.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, as not only do taxes play into it, but so does the cost of living.  You can't come close to comparing two jobs paying 100k a year, one in downtown NYC and one in Baton Rouge, LA.  You'll be living in a closet in Brooklyn with the first job, and in a four bathroom luxury apartment with the other.  It's up to candidates to determine if a salary is worth it.

Answer (score 12):

Unless the job posting says otherwise or you're very familiar with the country the job is in, assume pre-tax.

As the commenters pointed out, tax situation varies from person to person so it's rather unlikely to see a "take home" pay listed on a job posting... although it could potentially vary by country.